# When creating localiap purchase there’s no receipt

Tags: in-app-purchase, store, theos, tweak

Okay so I’m making a tweak , when I purchase the app it works fine ( using transactionstate 1 ) , but after I close the app I have to re do the purchase every time .. can someone help.. I’ve tried iapcrackers but they do the same thing.. it’s like there’s no receipt or transactions not saving..

Comment: It's hard to help with so little information. I assume you have built an app and implemented local receipt validation? Have you done it yourself, or are you using a framework for that? Or could the lack of receipt validation be the reason for your "problem"?

Comment: No I’m tweaking an apps payment method to respond with payed , and it works just there is no receipt so I have to keep doing payment every time I launch app.. how could I generate a custom receipt ?

Comment: How do you try to access the receipt?

Comment: I don’t have a method to access receipt .. for most apps you change transaction state to 1 then after purchase it saves receipt. But for this app it’s not working , I have seen other people make receipt but I’m unsure how so am asking , if you know please help bro

Answer (score 1):

Receipt validation is too complex to explain here. To get a brief overview, I recommend you to read the [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique) from Apple about possible receipt validation techniques and to watch the WWDC video linked in the article.

After you get a brief overview, you can decide if you want to go with local or server receipt validation. As with everything, both have their advantages and disadvantages.

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't provide a good article about local receipt validation and so far I haven't found a framework doing this correctly (as I would expect it). Although, it can be a good start without the hurdle of thinking about server communication.
If you go with the local receipt validation, I recommend you to use [TPInAppReceipt](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt) to access the receipt and its fields.

For server receipt validation there is this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store) from Apple, describing roughly the steps you need to do.

Apart from that, there are some third-party solutions for server receipt validation like [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/), [ChurnFighter](https://churnfighter.io/), and [Qonversion](https://qonversion.io/).